# What is the difference in these 2 bashrc checks for interactivity?

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian

In one (Debian shell) I have:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

In another (Debian shell) I have:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

What are the differences and which one should I choose nowadays?

Answer (score 3):

The test for `i` in the `$-` special parameter tests whether the current shell was started as an interactive shell.

Testing whether `$PS1` (the primary prompt string) is empty or not also works (most of the time) in the bash shell (and that shell only) at detecting whether the shell is interactive by accident because:

- bash ignores a `$PS1` that is in the environment if it's not started as an interactive shell, even in those cases where bash still reads `~/.bashrc` (like when started over `ssh` in some non-default build of bash or when `~/.bashrc` is sourced explicitly).
- in interactive invocations, if there's no `$PS1` in the environment, `bash` sets `$PS1` to `"\s-\v\$ "`.

So in `bash`, `$PS1` is generally set when interactive and unset when non-interactive.

That hack fails though if there's a `$BASH_ENV` file that sets `$PS1` (as `$BASH_ENV` files are interpreted even by non-interactive invocations) or if there's a `$PS1` with an empty value in the environment, or if `~/.bashrc` was sourced by a non-interactive shell after `PS1` has been set for a reason or another (like via `/etc/profile` for a non-interactive login shell), though all of those are unlikely in practice.

In Korn-like shells (ksh88, ksh93, pdksh, mksh, oksh, bash, zsh...), you can also do `[[ $- = *i* ]]` or `[[ -o interactive ]]` (the latter not with `bash` though).

But the `case $- in (*i*)...; esac` approach is by far the most reliable and portable, so there's little reason to use anything else.

Comment: Impressive answer! And my last question is: in your opinion, which one should I choose nowadays?